# Copy or move list items to archive list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, move

How to move list items(+2500 items) from the original list to another list(Archive)? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tree options to do:

Solution 1- Using content and structure page to move files with version and metadata:

Go to Site setting-->Click 'Content and Structure' link under Administration section
Pick the items/files to be moved, Click on Actions >> Move
Select the target list or library and click "OK" to complete move operation.

Solution 2- Move files between document libraries programmatically using Power Shell:

```
#For MOSS 2007 compatibility

[void]
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")



Function global:Get-SPWeb($url)

{

  $site= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)

        if($site -ne $null)

            {

               $web=$site.OpenWeb();        

            }

    return $web

}



#Get the web and List

 $Web = Get-SPWeb "<a class="vglnk" 
href="http://intranet.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing/" rel="nofollow">
<span>http</span><span>://</span><span>intranet</span><span>.</span>
<span>sharepoint</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span>
<span>sites</span><span>/</span><span>Marketing</span><span>/</span></a>"

$SourceList = $web.Lists["Proposals"]

$TargetList = $Web.Lists["Proposal Archive 2009"]



#Get all Files Created in 2009

 $Query = '<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value 
IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2009-01-01T00:00:00Z</Value></Geq>
<Leq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" 
Type="DateTime">2009-12-31T23:59:59Z</Value></Leq></And></Where>'

 $SPQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

 #$SPQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'" #To include Sub-folders in 
the library

$SPQuery.Query = $Query

 $SourceFilesCollection =$SourceList.GetItems($SPQuery)



Write-host "Total number of files found: "$SourceFilesCollection.count



#Move each file to the destination folder

foreach($item in $SourceFilesCollection)

{

  #Get the Source File

  $file = $Web.GetFile($item.File.URL)



  #Get the Month value from the File crated date

  $MonthValue = $item.File.TimeCreated.ToString('MMMM')



  # Try to Get the Sub-Folder in the Library!

  $TargetFolder = $TargetList.ParentWeb.GetFolder($TargetList.RootFolder.Url 
+ "/" +$MonthValue);



  #If the folder doesn't exists, Create!

  if ($TargetFolder.Exists -eq $false)

   {

     $TargetFolder = $TargetList.Folders.Add("", 
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $MonthValue)

    $TargetFolder.Update() 

   }



   #Move the File

   $file.MoveTo($TargetFolder.Url + "/" + $File.name)



}
```

Solution 3: Move files using SharePoint designer

• Open your site in SharePoint Designer

• Go to All Files >> Navigate to source library. Select files you want to copy/move,    choose cut/copy

Go to your target library, Right click and choose "Paste"

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's **Content and structure** page includes a **Move**-tool which can be used with list items. By using Content and structure, you can multi-select items and perform them the same action at once.

To access Content and structure, go to **Site settings** > below **Site Administration** -category, open **Content and structure**.

Comment: The Move button is hide. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Sai it should look e.g. like [this](https://blog.henryong.com/2008/01/21/how-to-movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-and-preserve-metadata-properties-at-the-same-time/). Are you doing the same actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use List back-up a template and later create a new list using this template.
Goto **List Settings -> Save this List as a template -> check Include Contents -> OK**

now you can create a new list using this template. GoTo **Site Contents -> Add an App -> Select your list template -> OK**

[image]